# Forward (or Backward filling) in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas, window-functions

The problem is to fill missing values in a table. In [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org), one can use forward (or backward) filling to do so as shown below:

```
$> import pandas as pd
$> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [None, 1, None, None, 2, None, 3, None]})
$> df['y'] = df['x'].fillna(method='ffill')
$> df
    x   y
0 NaN NaN
1   1   1
2 NaN   1
3 NaN   1
4   2   2
5 NaN   2
6   3   3
7 NaN   3
```

Is there a way to do that in SQL and more precisely in PostGres? I guess [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-window.html) could help but i couldn't figure out how.

In PostGres, it would be like:

```
sandbox=# SELECT x, ??
FROM
  (SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x) a;
 x 
---

 1


 2

 3

(8 rows)
```

Comment: where is the table? what missing values are you trying to fill out?

Comment: I edited it, i forgot one crucial line of pandas which uses the fillna with forward filling that i want to reproduce on postgres

Comment: you will need function here - if you just `lag` window function here - you will get previous x, nut not next to previous. In other words you want some kind of RECURSIVE LAG here, to repeat not previous value, but previous defined value

Comment: I tried to cheat with last know good value in window. not sure if it what you are looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[window functions here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)

so many aliases since your query is very sensitive to order.
I added more empty `x` lines to prove it is prune to several empty lines...

```
select x,y from (
select r,x, case when y is not null then y else min(y) over (partition by x order by r) end y from (
SELECT row_number() over() r,x, case when x is not null then x else lag(x) over () end y
FROM
  (SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS x
   UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS x
   ) a
   ) b
order by r
   ) c
   ;
```

[image]

Comment: This is not generalizable as per answer from @Philip-Hurvitz

Answer (score 1):

The last answer works but is not generalizable. Here I just add another NULL value after record 7:

```
select unnest(array [null,1,null,null,null,null, 2, null, null,3]) as x
```

[image: input vector]

I also turn the query into a CTE for readability:

```
with
    a as (select unnest(array [null,1,null,null,null,null, 2, null, null,3]) as x
    )
  , b as (
    SELECT
        row_number() over () as r
      , x
      , case
            when x is not null
                then x
            else lag(x) over ()
            end              as y
    FROM
        a
)
  , c as (
    select
        r
      , x
      , case
            when y is not null
                then y
            else min(y) over (partition by x order by r)
            end as z
    from
        b
    order by r
)
select
    x
  , z
from
    c
;
```

[image]

Record 9 is part of the partition of NULL values and it takes on the MIN() of that partition, which is 1.

I do not have a generalizable solution, but just wanted to caution against the use of the previously shown method

Answer (score 0):

Recursive view works and is generalizable.

#1 - generating a base table with mising data samples:

```
create temp table base as 
with a as (select unnest(array [null,1,null,null,null,null, 2, null, null,3]) as value)
, b as (SELECT row_number() over () as id, value FROM a)
select * from b;

select * from base;
```

[image]

#2 create a recursive view:

```
WITH RECURSIVE base_ffill AS (
  SELECT id, value
  FROM base
  WHERE value IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, b.value as value_ffill
  FROM base a
  JOIN base_ffill b ON a.id = b.id + 1
  WHERE a.value IS NULL
)
SELECT id,  value
FROM base_ffill
ORDER BY 1;
```

[image]